# Error when building Mesos

Tags: mesos

I've been trying to build Apache Mesos on CentOS 7.
When I run make I get the following error:

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/11/apache-11.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.mesos:mesos:0.28.2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:11 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: unknown error and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 18, column 11
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.mesos:mesos:0.28.2 (/home/mesos-0.28.2/build/src/java/mesos.pom) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.mesos:mesos:0.28.2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:11 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: unknown error and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 18, column 11: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: unknown error -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
make[1]: *** [java/target/mesos-0.28.2.jar] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mesos-0.28.2/build/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Could someone point out the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved.

Open file /home/mesos-0.28.2/build/src/java/mesos.pom, in section bellow, add more line: `<relativePath>../../apache-11.pom</relativePath>`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
    <relativePath>../../apache-11.pom</relativePath>     # Add this line
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with Mesos 1.0.1.

### Symptom

```
Building mesos-1.0.1.jar ...
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/11/apache-11.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.mesos:mesos:1.0.1 (/home/mesos/mesos-1.0.1/build/src/java/mesos.pom) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:11 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 18, column 11: Connection timed out -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
make[1]: *** [java/target/mesos-1.0.1.jar] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mesos/mesos-1.0.1/build/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

### Solution

[Set proxy for Maven](http://nanxiao.me/en/set-proxy-for-maven/) fixed the issue.