# Error in building mesos1.5.0

Tags: ubuntu, arm, mesos

#### info

cpu:          ARMv7 processor rev 1 (v7l) x 4

memory:       2GB

Ubuntu:       16.04LTS(Xenial Xerus) 32bit

#### question

I attempt to build [Apache Mesos 1.5.0](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/building/)  in Ubuntu 16.04LTS. The building steps are:

```
# Update the packages.
$ sudo apt-get update

# Install a few utility tools.
$ sudo apt-get install -y tar wget git

# Install the latest OpenJDK.
$ sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

# Install autotools (Only necessary if building from git repository).
$ sudo apt-get install -y autoconf libtool

# Install other Mesos dependencies.
$ sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev python-six python-virtualenv libcurl4-nss-dev libsasl2-dev libsasl2-modules maven libapr1-dev libsvn-dev zlib1g-dev

$ wget http://www.apache.org/dist/mesos/1.5.0/mesos-1.5.0.tar.gz
$ tar -zxf mesos-1.5.0.tar.gz

# Change working directory.
$ cd mesos

# Bootstrap (Only required if building from git repository).
$ ./bootstrap

# Configure and build.
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure
$ make
```

However it encounters a problem in *make* step:

```
Building mesos-1.5.0.jar ...
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/11/apache-11.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.mesos:mesos:1.5.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:11 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Temporary failure in name resolution and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 18, column 11
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.mesos:mesos:1.5.0 (/home/lemaker/project/mesos-1.5.0/build/src/java/mesos.pom) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.mesos:mesos:1.5.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:11 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Temporary failure in name resolution and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 18, column 11: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Temporary failure in name resolution -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
Makefile:14487: recipe for target 'java/target/mesos-1.5.0.jar' failed
make[1]: *** [java/target/mesos-1.5.0.jar] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lemaker/project/mesos-1.5.0/build/src'
Makefile:773: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

How to fix this problem here?

Relative topics:

> [Error when building Mesos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456563/error-when-building-mesos)
>
> https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mesos-issues/201511.mbox/%3CJIRA.12905609.1445020212000.94850.1447780930977@Atlassian.JIRA%3E

Answer (score 0):

> [Mesos runs on Linux (**64 Bit**) and Mac OS X (64 Bit). To build Mesos from source, GCC 4.8.1+ or Clang 3.5+ is required.](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/building/#system-requirements)

---

If you don't need Java bindings for ARM you can build Mesos without it. Just configure it and explicitly disable Java. It will decrease build time.

```
../configure --disable-java
```

Remember ARM is not officially supported and not all test are passing (see [MESOS-8635](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-8635)) nor all dependencies works on ARM (see [GLOG-256](https://github.com/google/glog/issues/256))

Native bindings are deprecated in favour of API.

Comment: As you say, I can configure the optional features. Here I encounter another problem: [ld: final link failed: Memory exhausted](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-8655). The problem of memory size puzzles me~~

Comment: You can try to switch to Clang from GCC it usually requires less memory

Comment: mesos 1.3.2 is ok!